# Expected value of random variable in word problem

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, expected-value

I have the following problem in my probability course. I am asked to compute the expected value of a random variable $X$ defined as follows:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In the first step a number $Y_1$ is randomly (uniformly distributed) chosen among $\{0, \ldots, n\}$. In the second step a number $Y_2$ is randomly chosen among $\{0, \ldots, Y_1\}$. This procedure is continued until the $0$ is drawn. Let $X$ be the number of steps necessary for this.

The solution to this exercise is given as:

Let $X_n$ be the number of steps necessary, when $\{0, \ldots, n\}$ is the first set. Let $n \geq 2$. If the first draw is $k \neq 0$, then the number of remaining steps has the same distribution as $X_k$ and thus

$$ \text{E}(X_n) = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n \text{E}(X_k) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = k) ~~.$$

After that, some more derivation follows until an explicit formula for $X_n$ is derived. However, the stuff after the formular is clear.

My question is: How is this formula derived?

The formula would be true if

$$ X_n = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = k)$$

And, in fact, this was one explanation that was given on the blackboard, when this problem came up in a discussion.

However, since $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = k) = \frac{1}{n+1}$, the right hand side may not even be an integer, while the left hand side is.

$X_n$, from the word problem, is presumably defined on $\Omega := \{0, \ldots, n\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ - I would not know what else would be a suitable space. But then for some $\omega \in \Omega$ we had

$$ X_n(\omega) = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k(\omega) \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = k) ~~.$$

How would $X_k(\omega)$ even be defined for some $k < n$?

Comment: The meaning of your  $X_n = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n X_k \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = k)$ is not obvious. For example $X_n$ appears on both sides but presumably can take different values on each side.   By contrast $\text{E}(X_n) = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \text{E}(X_k) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = k)$ is meaningful and the $\text{E}(X_n)$ on each side do represent the same value

Comment: I don't understand. $X_n \neq X_k$ when $n \neq k$. What do you mean by "$X_n$ appears on both sides"?

Comment: Expanding the sum: $X_n = 1 +  X_1 \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 1) +  X_2 \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 2) + \cdots  +X_n \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = n)$ has $X_n$ on both sides but they are not necessarily the same value.  Your statement "$X_n \ne X_k$ when $n \not=k$" is also dubious as they are each a random variable which can take any value on the positive integers

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Thx

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please expand on why $X_n$ can presumably take different values on each side?

Comment: If on your first attempt you see $Y_1=n$ which means your next attempt is from the same position.  In that case the $X_n$ on the left will be one more than the $X_n$ on the right

Comment: In other words there is no justification for your equation $X_n = ...$ which mixes random variables and probabilities together.  The other equation can be viewed as the formula for the expected time to reach state 0 in a discrete time Markov chain with states $0, 1, 2, ..., n$ and with transition probabilities as specified in the problem. If $S_0$ is the initial state, $S_1$ the next state, and $X$ the total time to hit 0,  it is the same as the law of total expectation $$E[X|S_0=n] = \sum_{k=0}^n \underbrace{E[X|S_1=k,S_0=n]}_{1+E[X|S_0=k]}\underbrace{P[S_1=k|S_0=n]}_{1/(n+1)}$$

Comment: Another way to see that you cannot mix random variables and probabilities together as you have is to note that the $X_k$ variables are integers, but when multiplied by probabilities and summed in that way they are not necessarily integers. So, you are just making that equation up, it can be called the "law of total make things up" rather than the "law of total probability" or the "law of total expectation."

Comment: Awesome. I did realize that we are looking at a Markov process. Thank you very much. If you want to expand on that in an answer I'll gladly accept.